# We play a game. Let’s guess the sum of two dices. The winner is the one closer to the sum. What’s your strategy?

Tags: probability, game-theory

I have the following question, just as in the title.
Two players, let us name them A and B, play a game. 2 dice are rolled. Players A, B take turns to guess the sum. The one closer to the sum wins. **Note, the person only wins but does not get the sum as a reward.**

*I would like to ask whether the following strategy is best, for this particular game as well as games like this one in general.*

We go first and pick a number N such that the expected value of the absolute value of the difference between our number N and all the other ones is minimised.
That is, we minimise $\sum_{k=2}^{12}p(k)|N-k|$ and thus deduce N.

Comment: Why wouldn't both players guess $7$ every time?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  What do you mean "take turns"?  Does one guess first and then the other?  How are ties handled?  Is there any reason not to choose $7$ all the time?

Comment: @EthanBolker I believe if a given number has already been picked then it cannot be chosen again by the other player.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying probability distribution for two fair six-sided dice is as follow:
[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxmXA.png)

If you're looking for the best strategy in this scenario (e.g, one time or endless independent rolls & the person only wins but does not get the sum as a reward), **you would want to bet that your opponent's dice roll sum is 7 each and everytime**.